# PHP posting datetime to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, datetime

I can't figure this out, I'm sure it's very easy and I'm approaching it the wrong way. I have a mysql `items` db with a column name `datePur` and type `datetime`.

Sample data;

```
+---------------------+
| datePur             |
+---------------------+
| 2015-11-03 11:05:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2014-12-02 07:14:11 |
+---------------------+
| 2015-08-01 11:09:34 |
+---------------------+
```

I have two forms in my web app, **view** and **edit**.

The **view** form retrieves the db data and displays the date in a *read only* table field in the following format; (03-11-2015)

```
<td><input type='text' name='datePur' value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($datePur)); ?> disabled"></td>
```

This works as expected.

My **edit** form retrieves the same data, however this time allowing the user to edit the date if necessary. The date is displayed to the user in the following format (not what I want); (2015-11-03 11:05:00)

```
<td><input type='text' name='datePur' value="<?php echo $datePur; ?>"></td>
```

I use the following code to post the data to the database;

`edit.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
    $datePur = ($_POST['datePur']);
}
```

`function.php`

```
public function update($datePur) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE items SET datePur=:datePur");
            $stmt->bindParam(":datePur", $datePur);
            $stmt->execute();
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The form will only submit if I enter the date in the format Y-M-d h:i:s - the same format as it's presented. I can't for example enter 03-11-2015, as the form won't submit.

I'd like to keep the date format consistent to end users. I'd like the datetime **always** to be displayed to the end-user in the format *d-m-Y*. However I would like it inserted to the database in the format Y-M-d h:i:s

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you even try: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the date again when they update.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
    $datePur = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['datePur']));
}
```

However, I usually have issues with it converting the date correctly, so I wrote a function to convert the date.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-update'])) {
    $datePur = convertDate ($_POST['datePur']);
}

function convertDate ($date) {
    $date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);

    $date = explode("-", $date);

    return $date[2]."-".$date[0]."-".$date[1];
}



function convertTimestamp ($date) {
    $date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);

    $datetime = explode(" ", $date);
    $date = explode("-", $datetime[0]);
    $time = explode(':', $datetime[1]);

    $return = $date[2]."-".$date[0]."-".$date[1]." ".$time[0].":".$time[1].":00";

    if ($datetime[2] == 'PM' && $time[0] > 12) {
        $return = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+12 hours', strtotime($return)));
    }elseif ($datetime[2] == 'AM' && $time[0] == 12) {
        $return = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 hours', strtotime($return)));
    }

    return $return;
}
```

The function will work whether you use "/" or "-" as your date separator, but has to have a date in the format of "m-d-Y" as the initial date.

Comment: Using `/` the format is `m/d/Y`.  `1/29/2016` is a valid date `1-29-2016` is not.  When using `-` the format is `d-m-Y` as `29-1-2016`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver My function can accept both 01/29/2016 or 01-29-2016.  It does not use the `date` function so wouldn't matter if PHP would see it as a valid date.  It just depends on the user's preference is all.

Comment: @johnny_s No problem, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to display and save date by helper functions or methods.

```
// input format: d-m-Y H:i:s
function saveDate( $date_str )
{
   list( $date, $time ) = explode( ' ', $date_str );
   list( $d, $m, $y ) = explode( $date );
   return $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d.' '.$time;
}
```

and

```
// input format (from DB): Y-m-d H:i:s
function loadDate( $date_str, $need_time = true )
{
   list( $date, $time ) = explode( ' ', $date_str );
   list( $y, $m, $d ) = explode( $date );
   return $d.'-'.$m.'-'.$y.' '.( $need_time ? $time : '' );
}
```

That's all. You can display the time with this code:

```
<td><input type='text' name='datePur' value="<?php echo loadDate( $datePur ); ?>"></td>
```

... and save:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE items SET datePur=:datePur");
        $stmt->bindParam(":datePur", saveDate( $datePur ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datePur))` before binding it